# Finding largest distance (on number scale) between n pairs of numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to write an algorithm that finds the largest distance between two numbers, given n pairs of numbers.

Here is what I have so far.

Wire ints is my example numbers, with first pair being `1,10` and second pair being `1,10` and third pair being `7,7`.

```
wire_ints = [10, 1, 1, 10, 7, 7]
longest_cases = {}
largest_length = 0
q = 0
y = 0
leftcounter = 0
rightcounter = 1

while q < len(wire_ints):
    left_port = wire_ints[leftcounter]
    right_port = wire_ints[rightcounter]
    length_wire = left_port - right_port
    wire_length = abs(length_wire)
    leftcounter = leftcounter + 2
    rightcounter = rightcounter + 2
    q = q + 2
    y = y + 1
    if not longest_cases:
        largest_length = wire_length
        longest_cases[wire_length] = y
    elif wire_length == largest_length:
        longest_cases[wire_length] = y
    elif wire_length > largest_length:
        largest_length = wire_length
        longest_cases.clear()
        longest_cases[wire_length] = y

print(longest_cases)
```

This currently outputs `{9:2}`, and its not wrong. `9` is the greatest distance between any of these pairs of numbers. BUT, I want it to print `{9:1, 9:2}`.

The key in the dictionary refers to greatest length, and the value refers to the number of the pair in the original array. With the first 2 integers being pair 1, then the second pair 2, etc.

So, as the array has two pairs with the same length, it should output BOTH pairs in the dictionary.

I cannot figure this out.
Help!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question once you have got answers.

Answer (score 3):

This takes your initial input and converts it to a list of tuples. Then it calculates the absolute difference between the tuple members and puts that into a new list. Then your final output is created as index_list.

```
wire_ints = [10, 1, 1, 10, 7, 7]

new_list = [(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(wire_ints[::2], wire_ints[1::2])]
diff_list = [abs(x[0] - x[1]) for x in new_list]
index_list = [(x, index) for (index, x) in enumerate(diff_list) if x == max(diff_list)] 

print index_list
```

Just realised this could be compressed further

```
new_list = [abs(x-y) for (x,y) in zip(wire_ints[::2], wire_ints[1::2])]
index_list = [(x, index) for (index, x) in enumerate(diff_list) if x == max(diff_list)]
```

If you desperately want a dictionary, the best approach would probably be storing the max value as a key, and the pair numbers in a list or tuple as the value.

Comment: I had a similar answer except using `grouper` recipe from `itertools` but you're to fast for me :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as you can have only unique keys in dictionary, you should either use pair number as a key or use a list:

```
wire_ints = [10, 1, 1, 10, 7, 7]

longest_dict = []
longest_so_far = 0

for i in range(len(wire_ints)//2):
  j = i*2
  a, b = wire_ints[j:j+2]
  dist = abs(a - b)
  pair = [dist, i + 1]
  if dist > longest_so_far:
    longest_so_far = dist
    longest_dict = [pair]
  elif dist == longest_so_far:
    longest_dict.append(pair)

print(longest_dict)
#=> [[9, 1], [9, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is not keeping distance indexes in a list. You can provide it by the code below:

```
longest_cases = {}
wire_ints = [10, 1, 1, 10, 7, 7]

leftIndex = 0
rightIndex = 1

largest_length = 0
y = 1

while leftIndex < len(wire_ints):
    cur_length = abs(wire_ints[leftIndex] - wire_ints[rightIndex])

    if cur_length in longest_cases:
        currentList = longest_cases[cur_length]
    else:
        currentList = []

    currentList.append(y)
    longest_cases[cur_length] = currentList

    leftIndex = leftIndex + 2
    rightIndex = rightIndex + 2
    y = y + 1

resultList = []
resultCase = 0
for k in longest_cases:
    if k > largest_length:
        resultList = longest_cases[k]
        resultCase = k

for index in resultList:
    print resultCase, ":", index
```

Here is [the link](http://ideone.com/qX65xi) that you can see the result.